# How to copy blob from one container to another using Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

In Azure, I have Blob storage with two containers. Input and Output. I have file say Test1.csv, which after processing I want to copy to output container. I need to do this as a step in Azure Logic app. However I am not able to understand how to configure the Copy Blob action in Azure Logic app. I am not able to configure the source path URL correctly.

It gives error message file not found.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Copy blob action to copy blob, the simplest way to get the blob url is use the [Create SAS URI by path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblobconnector/#create-sas-uri-by-path) action. Then pass the url to the Copy blob action and the destination.

[image]

Except this way, you could use create blob to copy blob. Firstly use [Get blob content using path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblobconnector/#get-blob-content-using-path) to get the blob content, then use Create blob to upload the blob to the destination container.

[image]